# OP-1 mixer tracks 1 and 2 disabled

Tags: synthesizer

I've found that either though me tweaking it weird or though a botched update, my [Teenage Engineering OP-1](https://www.teenageengineering.com/products/op-1)'s mixer tracks 1 and 2 have become disabled.

When I go to the mixer screen, I can see track 3 in white and track 4 in red, but tracks 1 and 2 are faded to gray. The encoders still function and set the level of the track between 0 and 99, but the tracks are still dimmed and when in tape mode, on either track 1 or 2, pressing any key produces no sound. Though I can see the red vertical indicator going up and down with the sound and it's not capped mute for any of the tracks. Also the synth/drum mode icon still lights up for any of the tape tracks when pressing keys.

When in tracks 3 and 4, sound comes out of the OP-1 as expected.

Did I manage to misconfigure my OP-1 somehow? What do I do to reverse it?

I've updated to firmware 225 yesterday, but I don't see this being a firmware problem since it's been out for a while now and I think someone would have noticed there was a problem with it by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was eventually resolved by a restart.

I still don't have an answer to whether it is a valid state I somehow invoked without realizing the combination of actions that led me there, or whether it was a bug.

I'll accept a better answer and delete mine, if one is provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you press shift and one of the track numbers it allows you to toggle hearing the track. This lets you solo and do other cool things.

In your case just press shift + 1 then shift + 2.